# How to cascade a deletion in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have a course object. The course object has a set of tutorials and a set of applications. When I delete a course objects I want the associated set of tutorials and applications to get deleted. My course.hbm is as follows, and my application.hbm contains

```
<property name="appdatetime" type="timestamp">
    <column name="appdatetime" length="19" />
</property>
<property name="appstatus" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="appstatus" />
</property>
<property name="apptype" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="apptype" />
</property>

<many-to-one name="course" column="cid"/>
<many-to-one name="employee" column="empid" />
```

Comment: If you want urgent help, add a bounty to the question. Naming it as 'please help' will normally only steer people away.

Comment: Its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810404/hibernate-deletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your course object you need to set the cascade option on what I presume will be a bag or similar with a one-to-many inside.

```
<bag name="Tutorials" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
   <key column="someId" />
   <one-to-many class="Tutorial" not-found="ignore" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it should be cascade="all,delete-orphan"